# python modules difference: .c/.h vs. .py

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm very new to python, as i'm embedding it (in form of a static lib) in an ios/obj-c project. It's not possible for me to dynamically load python modules, so i would like to compile my modules along with python.
 For modules shipped with the python source this works (by modifying `setup.py` or `Module/Setup`), but when i downloaded a third party module i noticed, i don't fully understand the mechanism.

The modules shipped with python come with a `.c` file in the `Modules` dir as well as a `.py` file in the `Lib` dir.
My third party module just comes with `.py` files.

1.Why do those modules have different file extensions?
2.How to integrate a module coming with .py files in an embedded python version? Obviously pasting them in Modules/Setup does require some `.c` files.
3.Do these .c files have something to do with the Python C-Api?

I guess i'm missing something essential :) Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Some Python modules are created as extensions in C with a wrapper/binding in python.  A lot of the standard library is in C, and many 3rd party modules are too ( for example, the more popular mysql and postgresql modules are in c, though there are pure-python versions )

The extending python docs cover this - http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html

I can't answer your other questions though - I try not to touch C :)

Comment: Thanks! So if the .py files are just wrappers it should be possible to compile a .py module along with python?